# Please provide a valid cache path ERROR. Even if there's a storage(cache,sessions,views) folder

Tags: laravel, path, composer-php

Why does my "composer install/update" keeps giving me this error? I also cant run some php artisan command because it will give me the same error

[image: Please Provide a valid cache path]

I already created a storage folder with cache, sessions, and views inside it but its still invalid path.

I also checked my view.php and its pointing also here

view.php

[image]

I also working on windows

Error code:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   InvalidArgumentException  : Please provide a valid cache path.

  at C:\Users\SDG\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler.php:36
    32|      */
    33|     public function __construct(Filesystem $files, $cachePath)
    34|     {
    35|         if (! $cachePath) {
  > 36|             throw new InvalidArgumentException('Please provide a valid cache path.');
    37|         }
    38|
    39|         $this->files = $files;
    40|         $this->cachePath = $cachePath;

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler::__construct(Object(Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem))
      C:\Users\SDG\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider.php:92

  2   Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::Illuminate\View\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), [])
      C:\Users\SDG\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:799

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: What is "this error"? Please add all details (like the error message in text form, and your attempts to resolve the problem) to yuour question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase my bad i've edited the thread i added the error code and I also tried to create the necessary folders on storage like the framework(views,sessions,cache) folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the STORAGE_PATH in my .env or just comment out the line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
mkdir -p storage/framework/views
```

from root

- The **mkdir** command is used to create directories.
- The **-p** option ensures that any intermediate directories that don't
  exist will be created as well.
- We specify the target path as **storage/framework/views** to create the
  "views" folder inside the "**framework**" folder, which is inside the
  "**storage**" directory.

Or

- Open a terminal or command prompt.
- Navigate to the root directory of your Laravel project.
- Run the following commands:

```
cd storage/framework
mkdir views
```

These commands will navigate to the "storage/framework" directory and create a new folder named "views" within it. Now you have successfully created the "views" folder in the "storage/framework" directory. This folder can be used to store any necessary files related to your Laravel application.